# How can I customize the NavigationBar from a single file?

Tags: swift

I would like to have all the navigation bars in my app be configured using one file. I have created a file `UINavCon.swift` which defines a class `UINavCon` which inherits from `UINavigationController` and then sets the customizations of the navigation bar. Now, in my other class (inherits from `UITabBarController` and `UITabBarControllerDelegate`), I am running this code to create the navigation controller, but the customizations are not appearing:

```
let trackerNavCon = UINavCon.init(rootViewController: TrackerViewController())
let trackerTabItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Tracker", image:  UIImage(systemName: "plus.app.fill"), tag: 1)
trackerNavCon.tabBarItem = trackerTabItem
// ...
self.viewControllers = [homeVC, trackerNavCon, historyVC]
```

How can I get customizations to appear?

Note: I am using Swift 5 with no storyboards and no SwiftUI.

Comment: Why not use the appearance proxy?

Comment: @matt I didn't know about that method. Now I see that I can put the customizations into the SceneDelegate, but is there a way that I can keep the customizations in their own file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an extension and customize the function accordingly. You can add various arguments as well in the theme function.

```
import UIKit

extension UINavigationController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

   open override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   open override func awakeFromNib() {
       themeNavigation()
   }

   func themeNavigation() {
       self.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
   }
}
```